# sed to replace path to the image

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, sed, html

I need to replace path to the image in multiple xhtml files in directory. The files head part is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
<head>
```

Tried to do it with `sed` command, but it doesn't work. Possibly due specific sed version, but not sure. I have `GNU sed 4.4`

```
original path:
<img src="/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg"
I need replace to:
<img src="graphics/line.jpg"
```

I tried

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/\/api\/v2\/epubs\/urn:orm:book:381260143574\/files/graphics/g' '*.xhtml'
```

it return

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

also tried

```
sed -i ' ' 's/\/api\/v2\/epubs\/urn:orm:book:381260143574\/files/graphics/g' '*.xhtml'
it return
sed: can't read s/\/api\/v2\/epubs\/urn:orm:book:381260143574\/files/graphics/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read *.xhtml: No such file or directory
```

Is the `sed` suitable for this?

Comment: While you're developing a `sed` expression, I strongly recommend you don't use `-i` at all. Don't edit-in-place until your expression works as expected

Comment: Be aware you can use any character for `sed`'s substitution delimiter. So `sed 's=/path/to/somewhere=/replacement/path=g` is permitted and far more readable

Comment: The `*.xhtml` should not be inside quotes, otherwise it will not expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
sed -i.bak 's/\/api\/v2\/epubs\/urn:orm:book:381260143574\/files/graphics/g' *.xhtml


sed -i '.bak' --> sed -i.bak
'*.xhtml' --> *.xhtml
```

Another option if you don't want to escape the slashes is to use `rpl`.

On a Debian based distribution :

```
sudo apt install rpl

rpl -b "/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg" "graphics/line.jpg" *.xhtml

-b = backup
```

[Manual for rpl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/rpl.1.html)

Answer (score 5):

The `sed` utility is not generally suitable for editing XML or XHTML files. XML  is a structured document format and not line-oriented. Like many standard Unix text manipulation tools, the `sed` utility is line-oriented and does not handle things like the encoding or decoding of XML entities without extra effort.

Your example document contains the node (corrected to include `/>` at the end)

```xml
<img src="/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg" />
```

Since the whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines) inside nodes is arbitrary, and we don't know about further attributes of the `img` node or their ordering, this would be cumbersome to parse with `sed`.  We must also ensure not to replace the pathname anywhere else than in the `src` attribute of an `img` node.

Using a command-line XML parser to do this might look like this:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed   \
        -u '//img/@src[. = "/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg"]' \
        -v 'graphics/line.jpg' file.xhtml
```

We're using `xmlstarlet`, a reasonably well-known XML parser for the command line, to replace the value of each `src` attribute of each `img` node with the string `graphics/line.jpg` if the original value of the attribute was `/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg`.

The command writes the result of the operation to standard output, but you can get `xmlstarlet` to do in-place editing using its `--inplace` (or `-L`) option after testing to make sure that it seems to be working as you expect it to work.

---

If your `img` tags look like `<img src="...">`, with no proper ending, then you may recover from this by first filtering your XHTML files though

```bsh
xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.xhtml
```

One could even envisage a pipeline on the form

```bsh
xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.xhtml |
xmlstarlet ed   \
        -u '//img/@src[. = "/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg"]' \
        -v 'graphics/line.jpg'
```

---

If the files that you want to process all match the pattern `./*.xhtml`, i.e., if they have a `.xhtml` filename suffix and are in the current directory, then you would be able to process all those files with either of the above commands using a simple shell loop.

```bsh
for name in ./*.xhtml; do
        xmlstarlet ed --inplace        \
                -u '//img/@src[. = "/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg"]'   \
                -v 'graphics/line.jpg' "$name"
done
```

Note that this uses the `--inplace` option of `xmlstarlet`, which would modify the files without making backups.  It would be best if you ran this on backed-up data.

To run the above on all XHTML files in a directory hierarchy, i.e., in a directory with several subdirectories, you may use `find`.

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.xhtml' -exec sh -c '
        for name do
                xmlstarlet ed --inplace        \
                        -u "//img/@src[. = \"/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg\"]" \
                        -v "graphics/line.jpg" "$name"
        done' sh {} +
```

Comment: how to batch process multiple .xhtml files in above example?

Comment: @minto See updated answer.

Comment: first I need normalize all .xhtml files, as xmlstarlet can deal _only_ with properly formatted XML documents. Not clear, how to use this shell loop first for filtering the XHTML files through the `xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.xhtml` and saving output as files. Without first formatting .xhtml docs,  xmlstarlet just print a plenty warnings "Opening and ending tag mismatch:", "Premature end of data in tag","Warning: unrecognized option '--in-place', Segmentation fault".

Comment: I tried this command `xmlstarlet ed -u '//img/@src[. = "/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/"]' -v 'graphics/' file.xhtml` but it doesn't change image path on stdout.

Comment: @minto If you look a bit further up, in my answer, you will find a pipeline that runs a document through`xmlstarlet fo` and then pipes it to `xmlstarlet ed`. It would be trivial to use that in the loop to write the resulting documents to new files.

Comment: I tried shell loop sample `for name in ./*.xhtml; do ....`, but it show `Warning: unrecognized option '--in-place'
Segmentation fault` for each file.

Comment: @minto Did you try using `--in-place` with `xmlstarlet fo`?

Comment: no,  I used your example above, after words "using a simple shell loop." The files are already XML-compliant as they  were recovered before through the xmlstarlet. Or it's not?

Comment: @minto It seems I have misspelled the option. How irritating. The option should be written `--inplace` or `-L`.  I will update my answer.

Comment: still not work, no errors, but don't change path. Btw, some links are `<img src="/api/v2/epubs/urn:..` and some`<img class="icon1" src="/api/v2/epubs/urn:..` if that matter.

Answer (score 4):

If it's XHTML you can edit it with a proper XML editor. The advantage here is that it's impervious to layout changes to the file

First, fix your example to be XML (it is an XHTML document, after all),

```
<img src="/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files/line.jpg"/>
```

If your source document isn't really XHTML you can fix it up programmatically with

```
xmlstarlet format -H file.xhtml
```

You can edit the `src` attribute with `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl --update '//img/@src' --value 'graphics/line.jpg' file.xhtml
<img src="hello"/>
```

Or by combining both commands,

```
xmlstarlet fo -H file.xhtml 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet ed -u '//img/@src' -v 'graphics/line.jpg'
```

When you're ready, put the result into a temporary file and then replace the original with the modified version. (Or rename the original as a backup and use it as input to create a file with the original name.)

If you have multiple `<img/>` elements you can provide a structure path to them instead of just `//img`. If you only want to change only those that have a specific `src` attribute value that's possible too. But there isn't really enough detail in your question to address these possibilities usefully.

Comment: Thanks, all answers are extremely helpful. The first was the answer from @Gounou, I tried it first,  works fine. The pages are content sections for ebook, without added header's  part and closing html tags. I have also to replace closing images tags `>` with self-closing `/>` tag (no space): how can I do this with `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: If you need to close the `<img/>` tags then you're not dealing with XHTML.

Comment: this didn't edit image src: `xmlstarlet edit --update '//img/@src' --value 'graphics/line.jpg' file.xhtml`

Comment: @minto that's because your file isn't really XHTML. It's almost XHTML but not quite. You need to use the combining version I provided at the end of my answer

Comment: tried `xmlstarlet fo -H file.xhtml 2>/dev/null | 
 xmlstarlet ed -u '//img/@src' -v 'graphics'` but it returns: "-:2.6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"??> 
     ^", while the doc already have proper xml declaration at the top. Same result when use `--omit-decl` in command.

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` option requires its value to follow immediately, without any space in between. So you'd have to write `-i.bak`. With the space, `sed` interprets this as `-i` without a value (so the file would be changed in place) and `.bak` as the command to run, hence the error message. You'd also need to remove the quotes around `*.html` to allow the shell to expand the wildcard.

(Your second attempt basically has the same problem, but here the space as a command doesn't trigger an error message.)

By the way, you can make your `sed` command more readable by using a separator different from `/` so you don't need to escape the slashes in your string to substitute, e.g.:

```
sed -i.bak 's-/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:381260143574/files-graphics-g' *.xhtml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this `sed`. I have not included the `-i` flag as it is inappropriate while testing.

```
sed -E 's|(img src=").[^"]*(/.*)|\1graphics\2|' input_file
```

This will group the matches we need to retain while excluding that which we do not.

`(.*=.)` - Groups everything up to the last occurance of `=`

`.[^"]*` - Is an excluded match. `[^"]` is used to prevent the match going to the last `/` and matching up to the next `"`

`(/.*)` - Everything up to the second to the last `/` has been excluded while matching the remaining pattern after.

`\1graphics\2` - Two group matches were created, we can return them in any order we please. As `graphics` needs to be hardcoded after `=`, we can insert it immediately after returning the first grouped match `\1`

`|` - Pipes were used as delimiters as the data itself contains '/' slashes which will conflict with `seds` default delimiters.

**Output**

```
$ sed -E 's|(img src=").[^"]*(/.*)|\1graphics\2|' input_file
<img src="graphics/line.jpg"/>
```

Comment: For closing image tags `<img/>` this works for me: `sed -i.bak -E 's|(<img [^>]*[^/])>|\1/>|' file.xhtml`

Comment: @minto My code above will work with the closing tag also. It will only fail if the double quotes are not included.  Your code however does not seem to function as expected when I tested it.

Comment: Strange, it does add closing tag to all images.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly strong arguments against using `sed` for such a thing, and others have made these.

However, you might not be in a position to use the specialised tooling mentioned. So, if your input files are suitably predictable in their structure so as to allow `sed` to work, this is the way I would do it:

```
sed -ri.bak 's (src=").*/files/(.+[.]jpg") \1graphics/\2 g' *.xhtml
```

It’s trying (reasonably) hard to make sure it’s operating on the correct lines by mentioning a bit of context in the search expression.

A note on `sed` usage: the first character after the `s` command dictates the delimiter, which allows us to work with `/` without the need to escape.

Comment: Finally, xmlstarlet is not the right tool for X(HTML) manipulation. 
Plus it has an obvious bug in XML declaration. HTML Tidy + sed do job much better.