# XMLstarlet to fix image tags and replace path for images

Tags: xml, html, xmlstarlet, epub

I have multiple .XHTML files in the folder. The top declaration part is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
<head>
```

First, I don't want alter top head part.

I want process files in batch and fix two things,

1. terminate image end tags properly `'/>'`, same for `<hr/>` and `<br/>` tags.
2. replace path in all images (preserving name), i.e. from

`<img src="/v2/media/2004/05/draft/305/files/dbc0401.jpg" alt="Images" width="258" height="115">`
to

`<img src="graphics/dbc0401.jpg" alt="Images" width="258" height="115"/>`

Tried xmlstarlet (v1.6.1), `xmlstarlet fo --recover --html file.xhtml`

but it alters top declaration part, adding extra stuff at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
<head>
```

Also warns about invalid tag

```
file.xhtml:8.54: Tag section invalid
<div id="aber-content"><section epub:type="chapter">
                                                     ^
```

what is correct commands? First I need 'dry run' to see changes, if OK then apply in place.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670645/100397

Comment: edited.  The original head part is conformant EPUB3 document specification, I assume.

Comment: EPUB3 samples that I checked have `<!DOCTYPE html>' after xml version, so I have to add it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed to replace path to the image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670634/sed-to-replace-path-to-the-image)